# Django user authentication with Azure AD and app roles

Tags: django, azure, azure-active-directory, django-microsoft-authentication

**Outline**

I want to integrate Azure Active Directory for authentication and authorization.

**Question**

How do I integrate the `msal` library into a Django web app, because the official Azure examples are using Flask?

And how to map the `AppRoles` I have defined in the Azure AD app registration to Django groups defined in the Django backend?

Answer (score 1):

[There are samples both for Flask and Django](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#web-applications). MSAL itself is framework agnostic so it can be used in any. Regarding the app roles claims you can inspect the [acquire_token*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/msal/msal.application.clientapplication?view=azure-python#msal-application-clientapplication-acquire-token-by-auth-code-flow) methods result. It's a dict containing `access_token` and/or `id_token` which will contain the `role` claim.